# Emacs auto-indenting comments in an unhelpful manner

Tags: indentation, comment

New Emacs user here. Hitting enter after a semicolon commented line in any file type (.el and .lisp at the very least) indents the comment in a very unhelpful way that I have to assume is not intended behavior. This problem does not occur if I move away from that comment line in any way besides hitting return (triggering auto-indent presumably).

For example, If I type the following

```
; this is a comment
```

Then hit return, I get the following (32 spaces indentation)

```
                                ; this is a comment
```

What is causing this behavior, and how can I prevent it?

I am running Emacs 26.3.0.20191219 installed through Chocolatey on Windows 10

Comment: Use two semicolons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unable to post this as a comment, but the indentation is likely part of one of the active modes (probably `lisp-mode` based on your description).
You can do <kbd>M+x</kbd> `describe-modes` to see which modes are active.

This answer provides some background on the history of the common lisp commenting style https://stackoverflow.com/a/6365579

This question and answers describe why the single `;` indents differently than multiple consecutive `;` characters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190488/set-comments-at-the-same-indentation-level-as-all-forms, namely that `lisp-indent-line` hardcodes it with the following comment

```
          ;; Single-semicolon comment lines should be indented
          ;; as comment lines, not as code.
```